# Swift unwind segue in viewWillDisappear on NavigationBar back button clicked

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

I'm trying to change a label text with unwind segue in viewWillDisappear function. Every time the viewWillDisappear function is called, it automatically skips my unwind segue line instead of executing it.

I'm using Xcode 9 and Swift 4.2

These are my codes:

main page ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

struct globalConstant {
   let lostMessage : String = "You Lost!"
   let welcomeMessage : String = "WELCOME"
   let playAgainMessage : String = "Play again"
   let resumeMessage : String = "Resume"
   let pausedMessage : String = "Game is paused"
   let playMessage : String = "Play Game"
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

var globalConst = globalConstant()
var labelValue : String!

//start Outlet
@IBOutlet weak var mainLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
//end Outlet


@IBAction func unwindFromGame(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue){

    let gameController = sender.source as? gamePageViewController
    if (gameController?.balVariables.balanceValue)! <= 0{
    mainLabel.text = gameController?.balVariables.abc
    }
    else  {
        mainLabel.text = self.globalConst.pausedMessage
    }
  }
}
```

my second page gamePageViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

struct balanceVariables {
//declare var start
var initBalance : Int = 500
var balanceValue : Int = 0
let abc = "abc"
//declare var end
}

class gamePageViewController: UIViewController {

//   override func addChild(_ gamePageViewController: UIViewController) {

//   }

@IBOutlet weak var valueHolder: UILabel!

var balVariables = balanceVariables()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //run on page load

    if balVariables.balanceValue <= 0 {
        balVariables.balanceValue = balVariables.initBalance
        valueHolder.text = String(balVariables.balanceValue)
    }else{
        balVariables.balanceValue = balVariables.balanceValue
    }

}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindFromGame", sender: self)
}


//    override func didMove(toParent ViewController: UIViewController?){
 //       performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindFromGame", sender: self)
//    }
```

}

Here is the image of my storyboard configuration
(for the unwind segue connection, I ctrl+dragged the View Controller icon 
to exit icon in `gamePageViewController`)
[image: StoryBoard Configuration]

As mentioned, I couldn't get performSegue to run in `viewWillDisappear`.
What I'm trying to achieve here is when I click the back button on NavigationBar, the `viewWillDisappear` will intercept and perform an unwind segue to the main ViewController which calls `unwindFromGame` and changes `mainLabel`.

From the code in `gameViewController.swift`, you'll notice that I have commented out `didMove(toParent)`. Using this method, I could get my `performSegue` to run and it successfully retrieved the `abc` variable from `gamePageViewController` but the problem is that it loaded the page but didn't wait for my prompt on the back button. Instead it automatically ran `didMove(toParent)` and sent me back to my main screen with `mainLabel` edited. I've tried `willMove(toParent)` as well and I achieved the same result.

My questions are :

How do I get `performSegue` in `viewWillDisappear` to run?

Is this an iPhone X / iPhone Xs Max related issue?

Using `didMove(toParent)` or `willMove(toParent)`, how do I get it to wait for my prompt on the back button?

Let's say it's not possible to get it to work with NavigationBar Back Button. Will a custom NavigationBar Back Button achieve expected result? If so, how should I do it?

Do you recommend switching to Swift 4 instead of 4.2?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try it with delegate pattern not with using unwind segue.

Firste create delegate protocol for your `gamePageViewController` and declare function for sending `balanceVariables`

```
protocol GamePageDelegate {
    func sendBalVariable(_ variable: balanceVariables)  
}
```

now create `delegate` variable in your `gamePageViewController`

```
class gamePageViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: GamePageDelegate?
    ...
}
```

Then implement this delegate to your `ViewController` and declare what should happen when you call this method on delegate

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GamePageDelegate {
    ...
    func sendBalVariable(_ variable: balanceVariables) {
        if variable.balanceValue <= 0 {
            mainLabel.text = variables.abc
        } else {
            mainLabel.text = self.globalConst.pausedMessage
        }
     /* mainLabel.text = variable.balanceValue <= 0 ? variables.abc : self.globalConst.pausedMessage */
    }
}
```

now override `prepare(for:sender:)` in your `ViewController` and set destination's `delegate` as `self` (if segue's identifier matching with identifier of your segue between `ViewController` and `gamePageViewController`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! gamePageViewController
        destinationVC.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Finally in your `gamePageViewController` call method on delegate when view will disappear and ass parameter pass `balVariables`

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    delegate?.sendBalVariable(balVariables)
}
```

Comment: @StevenStuu don't use any unwind segues, use what I wrote. "yourIdentifier" is identifier for segue from `ViewController` to the second

Comment: what should the "yourIdentifier" be? The line  destinationVC.delegate = self is giving me an error : Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'delegate'

Comment: Do you see this arrow between first and second VC in storyboard? Click on it and at the right side you will see text box and there write yourIndetifier

Comment: I've added an identifier in the segue between the main VC and the second VC in storyboard and the error still persist.

Comment: @StevenStuu and did you override prepare method how I had described?

Comment: yes I did. Here's the full function code.  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "mainPageSegue"{
            let destVC = segue.destination
            destVC.delegate = self
        }
    }

Comment: @StevenStuu sorry, my mistake add this behind declaring destinationVC `as! gamePageViewController` --> `let destinationVC = segue.destination as! gamePageViewController`

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! Merry Christmas and Happy Holidays!

Comment: @StevenStuu you too... :-)